# #1271 - Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to write a select-union query, but allways getting this error:
**#1271 - Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'**

Mysql query:

```
SELECT users.*, offices.name as office_name FROM huilo_daikiri.`users` left outer join offices on (offices.id=users.office_id) where users.id='120'
union all
SELECT users.*, offices.name as office_name FROM huilo_laroc.`users` left outer join offices on (offices.id=users.office_id) where users.id='185'
```

When I separate it for 2 SELECTs - it works.

What I'm doing wrong? Thx.

Comment: Can you post the ddl for the 2 tables? Also is the data definition for the NAME column on the "OFFICES" table different from that of the NAME column on the "OFFICESA" table?

Comment: One or more columns have different collations and can't be mixed into the same column. But you can forace a collation in a select like this: `select col1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS from your_table` for instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have columns in the two tables with different collations. Look at the COLLATE keyword in Books Online.

Comment: That should rather be a comment